# How do I validate this html?

Tags: html, validation

I designed a website for a company and everything works great. I decided that i might as well validate the whole thing so Ive been crushing errors. However, I came across this problem that I can't seem to figure out. 

here is the error

```
Line 86, Column 106: Bad value 105px for attribute height on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.

Line 86, Column 106: Bad value 216px for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.
```

Here is the line

```
<p class="centeredImage"><img src="images/logo.png" height="105px" width="216px" alt="ATS Logo"><img src="images/header1.png" alt="ATS Header"></p>
```

I am using the p class of centeredImage to obviously center the two images in the div. I thought removing the two 'p' tags would fix it but it still gives me the same error. It seems to be a problem with the actual height and width attributes.

Can someone tell me what is going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height and width attribute do not require the "px" to be there http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_height.asp

Comment: This fixed my issue. Will accept as answer whenever timer lets me. Thank you!

Comment: @onTheInternet - Actually, all four answer you've got so far should fix your issue ;-)

Comment: Please do not recommend w3schools as a valid reference.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - Have you noticed that if you google for "W3C img" you get W3Schools as first result? It's crazy...

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - I'm not claiming w3schools is without error, just as is this site.  Just like any informative online source, you need to be aware of it's accuracies/inaccuracies.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario yeah, it's rather unfortunate. [Personal Blocklist](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/personal-blocklist-by-goo/nolijncfnkgaikbjbdaogikpmpbdcdef) is pretty useful for stuff like this.

Comment: @JustinBicknell w3schools being "not without error" is a huge understatement. Even the page you linked (which incidentally is nothing to do with images as the question asked) has errors and bad practice. You simply can't compare it to Stack Overflow, whose occasional errors are often voted down or corrected in due course.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat - images are irrelevant, the link was VALID since it conveyed the point I was making - re height and width attributes

Answer (score 6):

The `width` and `height` attributes have nothing to with CSS. They just expect a number.

Link: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img

Comment: I didnt write anything about css in my post. I know they expect a number. And im clearing defining numbers. So what is the issue?

Comment: `px` is a CSS suffix. HTML simply doesn't support it. Image dimensions need to be in pixels, you aren't allowed to change units.

Comment: @onTheInternet: `"And im clearing defining numbers"` - No you're not, you're defining strings which you intuitively interpret as numbers.  For example, `"105px"`.  HTML doesn't interpret that as a number, because the characters `p` and `x` aren't numeric.  The specification says it has to be an integer, not a string which a person reading it might interpret as an integer.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for your help. All answers will be marked as helpful

Answer (score 2):

Height and with are by default expressed in **px** adding "**px**" to the value makes a validation error. You should write your tag like:

```
<img src="images/logo.png" height="105" width="216" alt="ATS Logo">
```

The height and width is interpreted as pixels. If you require the width or height as percent of space is necessary to add "%" after the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

u have used

```
height="105px" width="216px"
```

whereas it should be

```
height="105" width="216"
```

don't use px there..